# How to convert string variable which is in UTC to AEST('Australia/Melbourne') timezone using python code

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I want to convert string variable which is in UTC format to AEST(Australia/Melbourne) timezone format using python

Variable TEST_START(String) is in UTC timezone and It's value shows 2023-11-21 09:41:16 UTC. I want to convert the UTC to AEST.

**Code**

```
import pytz
tz_aest = pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne')
```

Don't know who to apply AEST timezone to variable TEST_START string variable.

Comment: do you mean time difference or datetime format?

Comment: in your specific case, you could use `datetime.fromisoformat("2023-11-21 09:41:16 UTC".replace(" UTC", "+00:00", 1)).astimezone(ZoneInfo("Australia/Melbourne"))`

Comment: fromisoformat throwing error

Comment: If you receive specific errors for code you try, please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77521883/edit) them to the question. Make sure to include relevant details such as your Python version.

Comment: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: ''

Comment: @user13748181 are you doing the string replace of `" UTC"` as suggested? Does your `TEST_STRING` have any extra trailing whitespace? Could you post exactly what you are inputting into `fromisoformat`?

Comment: dateutc = datetime.fromisoformat(self.TEST_START.replace(" UTC", "+00:00", 1)).astimezone(timezone("Australia/Melbourne"))

Comment: and what does `print(self.TEST_START)` and `print(type(self.TEST_START))` output?

Comment: 2023-11-21 09:41:16 UTC.

Comment: *** test start *** <class 'str'>

Comment: you cannot parse `*** test start ***` to a datetime. if you expect such invalid data, try using a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: If your `TEST_START` string contains text other than the date/time string, you could consider using a regular expression to extract just the date, e.g., have `import re` at the start of you script and use: `re.search("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[.\d+]* UTC", self.TEST_START).group()` to extract the date/time.

Comment: how we can convert UTC time to AEST

Comment: utc_time = datetime.now(pytz.utc) .. how can we convert this to AEST

Comment: Again, the comments section is not appropriate for discussion of such details. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77521883/edit) your question.